# Emberjs : Access to object variable in hbs template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to find object by name and access to my object in hbs template.
Actually, I have this :

```js
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   var twitter = this.store.find('service', { name: "twitter" });
    alert(twitter.Name);
  }
});
```

And in my template have this :  {{twitter.name}}

My object is loaded, but i cannot access. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your code has some very obvious errors, please take a look at this guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/

Answer (score 0):

> And in my view have this : {{twitter.name}}

That is handlebars mark up and it is used in your **templates**, not views. Use proper terms to avoid confusions later.

Your model hook must **return** the data:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var twitter = this.store.find('service', { name: "twitter" });
    alert(twitter.Name);
    return twitter;
  }
});
```

The model is set as a property of your controller and your template receives it from the controller. In your template you access the values of your model, from the controller,  directly:

```
Twitter name: {{Name}}
```